# Как в списке найти определенный пункт и удалить его?

Tags: jquery, javascript, html

Добрый ночи друзья, у меня есть список

```
<ul>
     <li>Пункт</li>
     <li>Пункт</li>
     <li>Пункт</li>
     <li>Пункт</li>
     <li>Пункт</li>
</ul>
```

Мне надо найти пункт 3 и удалить, кто поможет?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
jQuery("ul li:eq(2)").remove();
```

или так:

```
jQuery("ul li").eq(2).remove();
```

Или так

```
jQuery('ul').find('li').each( 
        function(){ 
                if(jQuery(this).index() == 2) 
                            jQuery(this).remove(); 
});
```

Comment: Спасибо! сделай его нормальным ответом